# Is there a way to apply a boolean predicate to a set of object properties in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, method-reference

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to code the following that leverages some combination of streams, lambdas and method references:

```
final boolean valid = StringUtils.hasText(obj.getFirstName())
                && StringUtils.hasText(obj.getLastName())
                && StringUtils.hasText(obj.getGender())
                && StringUtils.hasText(obj.getDob());
```

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
final boolean valid =
       something(StringUtil::hasText, 
                 obj.getFirstName(),
                 obj.getLastName(),
                 obj.getGender(),
                 obj.getDob());
```

Or perhaps:

```
final boolean valid =
       something(StringUtil::hasText, obj,
                 Type::getFirstName(),
                 Type::getLastName(),
                 Type::getGender(),
                 Type::getDob());
```

Obviously you could put all the getters into a List and then use a stream, but that seems very wordy.    It seems to me that there might be library function that does something like this, either in the JRE or perhaps in Spring or Apache.

Comment: That `something` method probably fits on 2 lines, you could just write it...

Comment: `Stream.of(a, b, c).allMatch(StringUtils::hasText)`

Comment: @Michael that's definitely a valid answer in my eyes :)

Comment: But *why*? Is it really so troublesome to write the chain of `&&` checks? If the class of `obj` has very many attributes you need to check, that suggests that the design of that class is faulty.

Comment: The issue isn't how much time it takes to "write" the code.    

The issue is how much time it takes to "read" and understand it.   In other words the "exposition" of what the code is doing.

These days I think there's far too much concern on how long it takes to "write" something and not focus on how long it takes to "understand" what was written.

Answer (score 5):

Using anything else but your current approach is just making things worse. Even if you were to create a method to perform the "and" logic given some arguments of input you're eventually going to end up with the same amount of code if not more and definitely will be less memory friendly.

You could use the `allMatch` as suggested in the comments:

```
Stream.of(obj.getFirstName(), obj.getLastName(), obj.getGender(), obj.getDob())
      .allMatch(StringUtils::hasText)
```

but as you can see this is much more complicated and less readable.

The conclusion is I wouldn't change a thing with your current approach. If you're having to perform this check many times then you'll probably need to take a step back and rethink your design.

Comment: I surely do NOT agree that what I'm asking for is making things worse.   

The "exposition" of the alternative you've suggested is, IMHO, much better:  "Here's a list of the values", here's the (common) predicate they must satisfy".

Exposition here is the difference between "x must be between 10 and 20, y must be between 10 and 20" and z must be between 10 and 20", and "x,y and z must all be between 10 and 20".

What's more is that the current method is programmatical, whereas the other way can be a set of values that's passed in.

Comment: I think one of the reasons people might think the original way is easier to understand is because people just aren't quite yet used to streams.     It's not that the old way is better (IMHO it's not), it's that it's more "familiar".

I think Streams are, for example, considerably better and easier to understand than for-each statements to do things like filtering.

Answer (score 3):

I would write a method that takes the predicate and getter functions:

```
static <T> boolean validate(Predicate<String> condition, T object, 
        Function<T, String>... functions) {

    boolean res = true;

    for(Function<T, String> f: functions) {
        res &= condition.test(f.apply(object));

        if(!res) return false;
    }

    return res;
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
boolean allValid = validate(StringUtils::hasText, myObject, 
        MyClass::getFirstName, MyClass::getLastName, MyClass::getGender);
```

Of course, `Function<T, String>` may need to change to `Function<T, Object>` if `hasText` takes `Object`.

Comment: That's kinda what I had in mind, but I was hoping that this existed in a library already.   Thanks.

Comment: There is no point in using the `&=` operator or the `res` variable, as you can just use `if(!condition.test(f.apply(object)) return false;` in the loop and `return true` after the loop. And it’s recommend to add the `@SafeVarargs` annotation to the method.